# Cyrillic alphabet in Multibyte

Tags: c++, unicode, mfc, cyrillic

I am pretty new to working with C++. I have an MFC project which needs be translated in to **Russian**.

If I change the MFC settings to **Unicode** it shows correctly. My question is:

Is it possible to print cyrillic alphabet with **Multibyte**? If so, how?

Thanks guys!

Comment: The answer to your question: it is possible.

Comment: Thanks Dialecticus. Do you have an example or page for documentation? It's my first time with non latin characters.

Comment: No, but you should ask a proper question when asking one. Instead of "is it possible" you should ask "how to". We can't be sure that you imply the latter when asking the former. Also, why not just use Unicode? You say it works, so just use it.

Comment: Sorry, I will be more specific and take more careful when I ask something in the future. 
Teammates said me gonna be better not use Unicode because it will fire up a lot of errors but I guess gonna be better use Unicode.

Comment: Er, if team mates tell you not to use Unicode, because they don't know how to use Unicode, you better look for a decent project. That one clearly ain't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encourage you to build your MFC application using **Unicode** (to be more precise: UTF-16 in MFC/Visual Studio settings), as you wrote *"If I change MFC to Unicode it shows correctly."*.

At the same time, you can still use another encoding like e.g. **UTF-8** for your Cyrillic text, and store this in `CStringA` or `std::string` objects. Then, you can convert between UTF-8 and UTF-16 at the "MFC boundaries", e.g. when showing your text on your dialog boxes or other application windows.

You can use some [ATL/MFC conversion helpers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx), or write your own conversion code invoking Windows APIs like `MultiByteToWideChar` and `WideCharToMultiByte`, specifying the proper "code page" for the conversion (e.g. `CP_UTF8` for UTF-8-encoded text).

You may find [this MSDN article on Unicode encoding conversions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt763237.aspx) helpful as well.

On the other hand, if you want to use a specific code page (e.g. [1251 Windows Cyrillic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195053.aspx)) instead of UTF-8, then you can still use `MultiByteToWideChar` to convert text from your code page to Unicode UTF-16, specifying the proper [code page identifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx).