# How to show Cyrillic text in MFC Multi-Byte application?

Tags: c++, mfc, cyrillic, multibyte

I am new with C++ and MFC. The main problem is that I have an MFC project that needs to be translated into Russian. I see that the best option is to change the project to Unicode but I cannot, because it is a huge project and when I change I receive more than 4000 errors. Later we will pass all the code to Unicode, but for now I just need to show Cyrillic on the buttons and CListBox.

Well, the main thing is: How to print Cyrillic with Multibyte?

Thanks guys!

PD: Sorry, I am gonna be more explicit with what I tried:

Use russian locales:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian_russia.1251");
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
```

But didn't work. Shows question marks.

Also I tried to convert with function WideCharToMultiByte. But shows characters that seems to be encoded wrong.

```
std::string utf8_encode(const std::wstring &wstr)
{
    if (wstr.empty()) return std::string();
    int size_needed = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, &wstr[0], (int)wstr.size(), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    std::string strTo(size_needed, 0);
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, &wstr[0], (int)wstr.size(), &strTo[0], size_needed, NULL, NULL);
    return strTo;
}

    wchar_t* wch = L"Привет";

    std::string ch = utf8_encode(wch);

    m_wndOutputBuild.AddString(ch.c_str()); //OUTPUT ÐŸÑ€Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ‚
```

PD2: Now I call like this

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian_russia.1251");

std::wstring wch = L"Привет";

std::string ch = encode_1251(wch);

m_wndOutputBuild.AddString(ch.c_str()); //OUTPUT Ïðèâåò
```

and Function:

```
std::string encode_1251(const std::wstring &wstr)
{
    if (wstr.empty()) return std::string();
    int size_needed = WideCharToMultiByte(1251, 0, &wstr[0], (int)wstr.size(), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    std::string strTo(size_needed, 0);
    WideCharToMultiByte(1251, 0, &wstr[0], (int)wstr.size(), &strTo[0], size_needed, NULL, NULL);
    return strTo;
}
```

I found that Windows-1251 puts CP like that on WideCharToMultiByte [here](http://rsdn.org/forum/winapi/919911.all).

Comment: I know, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48558810/cyrillic-alphabet-in-multibyte it doesn't work for me becouse I can't change to Unicode, my project it's a huge project. Also I tried to use locales but doesn't do any change. It's show question marks.

Comment: @Treith: I'm the one who suggested you to move to Unicode in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48559522/1629821), and I still think it's the best path. Anyway, if you and your team do want to keep your code base MBCS ("multi-byte"), I would suggest you to start with a simple MFC dialog-based application, and then insert there an edit control and a list-box. Read user input from the edit control, and add the line the user enters in the list-box. Use `CEdit::GetWindowText` to read the user input from the edit control, and `CListBox::AddString` to populate the LB. ...

Comment: ... You should see the exact same string the user entered appear in the list box. If you don't, then post your code here and the exact result. Start simple, and try to identify your exact problems. I'm not expert in MBCS/Cyrillic, so I cannot give better help.

Comment: Hi @Mr.C64, it's not my post. Only was an example solution that in my case doesn't work. But thanks, I gonna start with this.

Comment: @Treith: I noted you added more details and C++ code snippet in your question, so I added an answer based on this new pieces of information.

Answer (score 2):

In your `utf8_encode` function, when converting your Unicode UTF-16 string to a `std::string`, you passed `CP_UTF8` to `WideCharToMultiByte`. Then you take the returned UTF-8 `std::string`, and pass it via `.c_str()` to the `CListBox::AddString` method.

However, if your application is in MBCS Cyrillic, you should convert from UTF-16 to your **Cyrillic code page**, instead of UTF-8, and pass the strings encoded in your Cyrillic code page to your MFC class methods, like `CListBox::AddString`.

In other words, you may want to substitute your `utf8_encode` function with a `cyrillic_encode` function, that takes UTF-16 text as input, and converts it to your Cyrillic code page:

```
// Convert from Unicode UTF-16 to Cyrillic code page
std::string cyrillic_encode(const std::wstring &utf16)
```

And then pass the returned string to the MFC class methods of interest, e.g.:

```
// From Unicode UTF-16 to Cyrillic code page
std::string cyrillic_text = cyrillic_encode(wch);

// Show Cyrillic-encoded "MBCS" text
m_wndOutputBuild.AddString(cyrillic_text.c_str());
```

Moreover, as correctly pointed out by @IInspectable in the comments, consider adding proper error checking code in your conversion functions. In fact, in general, there can be UTF-16 text that *cannot* be properly encoded in Cyrillic, as the latter is a proper subset of the former.

Comment: It's probably also a good idea to check the return value of `WideCharToMultiByte` for errors, and/or pass the appropriate flags to gracefully deal with characters, that cannot be represented in the destination character set. An alternative solution would be to construct a `CStringA`, using a [conversion c'tor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class#cstringt) taking a `wchar_t*`. I believe the conversion is performed using the locale of the calling thread.

Comment: @IInspectable I agree.

Comment: Hi, I updated code. Ok, I gonna check return. But it seems like output it's not correct. Does I have selected main language cyrillic on Windows?

Comment: @Treith I don’t know. I have no experience with Windows in Cyrillic. I still believe the best thing you can do is to use Unicode UTF-16 at the Windows API/MFC boundary, and convert from whatever encoding to UTF-16 at the boundary, and just feed UTF-16-encoded text to Windows APIs and MFC wrapper methods.